# Selecting values for first and last date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I've ran into the task where I need to select initial (with the oldest date) and final (with the last date) values for an entity. I've managed to do it via multiple OVERs, but looks like it will be performance issue on prod data.

Is there any way to optimize my solution?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    InvoiceID, 
    FIRST_VALUE(ih.ApprovedTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceID ORDER BY ih.DateReviewed ASC) AS InitialTotal, 
    FIRST_VALUE(ih.DateReviewed) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceID ORDER BY ih.DateReviewed ASC) AS Initialdate, 
    LAST_VALUE(ih.ApprovedTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceID ORDER BY ih.DateReviewed ASC) AS FinalTotal,
    LAST_VALUE(ih.DateReviewed) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceID ORDER BY ih.DateReviewed ASC) AS FinalDate
FROM  
    tblInvoiceHistory ih
```

EDIT: if we have this data:

```
    InvoiceId  |  DateReviewed  |  ApprovedTotal
    --------------------------------------------
1   1          |  2015-1-1      |  10
2   1          |  2015-2-1      |  20
3   1          |  2015-3-1      |  30
4   2          |  2015-1-1      |  110
5   2          |  2015-2-1      |  120
6   2          |  2015-3-1      |  130
```

Desired output will be like this

```
    InvoiceId  |  InitialDate  |  InitialTotal  |  FinalDate  |  FinalTotal
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1          |  2015-1-1     |  10            |  2015-3-1   |  30
2   2          |  2015-1-1     |  110           |  2015-3-1   |  130
```

Comment: Do you want the total first and last date, or each InvoiceID's first and last date?

Comment: @jarlh each InvoiceID's

Comment: Then lad2025's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     InvoiceID
    ,[Initialdate] = MIN(ih.DateReviewed)
    ,[Finaldate]   = MAX(ih.DateReviewed)
FROM tblInvoiceHistory ih
GROUP BY InvoiceID
```

EDIT:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT 
     [InvoiceId]   = InvoiceID
    ,[MinDate]     = MIN(ih.DateReviewed)  
    ,[MaxDate]     = MAX(ih.DateReviewed)  
  FROM tblInvoiceHistory ih
  GROUP BY InvoiceID
  )
  SELECT  
    c.InvoiceId
   ,[InitialDate]  = c.[MinDate]
   ,[FinalDate]    = c.[MaxDate]
   ,[InitialTotal] = (SELECT ApprovedTotal FROM tblInvoiceHistory ih WHERE ih.InvoiceId = c.InvoiceId AND ih.DateReviewed = c.[MinDate])
   ,[FinalTotal]   = (SELECT ApprovedTotal FROM tblInvoiceHistory ih WHERE ih.InvoiceId = c.InvoiceId AND ih.DateReviewed = c.[MaxDate])
  FROM cte c
```

Comment: Problem is that I need not only dates, but also values from that date's rows

Comment: @Xandrmoro See updated. Do you have some key like row_number on this table or only InvoiceID and date?

Comment: There is no unique column in this table. And its still not exactly what I need (maybe bad description). I need to select ApprovalTotal column value for rows with the min and max dates.

Comment: @Xandrmoro If it is not desired Output please add EDIT: and below paste data and desired output.

Comment: @Xandrmoro Second query will get you InvoiceId with both dates min and max and then using join to the same table select all data from this table.

Comment: updated question. Selfjoin is still an option, yes, but I hope there can be simplier solution

Comment: @Xandrmoro See updated answer. I assume that InvoiceId and Date is UNIQUE.